Use of long, long long, signed, unsigned, etc in C++
Is it common programming practice to use unsigned, signed, long, long long, etc in our C++ programs? I have noticed that that's what my textbook does, but my lecturer doesn't do that. Does it have benefits to it in terms of program effectiveness, or a recommendation for programmers?
I have tried to use the method in the textbook, but I end up falling behind in my work because our lecturer codes the simple way and I always try to keep up with the textbook, but it takes me a while to catch up.

When I need to specify the size I use these instead: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Depends.  In the embedded systems world, the bit-width types are preferred and used.  For example, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t.  This relieves the programmer from having the compiler use 32 bits for a char.  I use unsigned int, int when bit width doesn't matter (like loop indices).

Depends on what you are doing.  On modern x86-64 and ARM systems int is 32 bits and is easy type for the CPU to handle.  If the range of the numbers you are working with fit in the range that int has then its a natural type to use. Once you get into a domain where you need to reasse that is when the other types can become useful.

When writing to hardware devices, the bit width types are very useful.  For example, we have an FPGA that has 16-bit width registers.  The type short is not guaranteed to be 16 bits.  It has a minimal range of 16 bits, but can be larger.  So we use uint16_t so there is no ambiguity when writing to 16-bit registers.

What alternative are you comparing with? The types with explicit bit sizes?

"my lecturer does't do that. Does it have benefits"  Benefits over what your lecturer does?  We would have to know what your lecturer is doing to answer that.

Your question is missing a mention of what your lecturer does do. Does your lecturer not use any integer types? It's very easy to expand the "etc" in "unsigned, signed, long, long long, etc" to include short, int, and all valid combinations of these keywords. Perhaps you meant to / should write "instead of simply int" somewhere in your question?

Yes, it's quite common. For small math, int alone does what you need, but when you get to more advanced usage (e.g. bit-twiddling, bit-masks, etc.), larger numbers, performance optimization, etc., people will use stuff other than plain int. That said, unsigned/long/long long (and int for that matter) are portability nightmares, so modern idiomatic C and C++ tend to use fixed width, least width, or fast-width integer types to guarantee a specific number of available bits (so if the same code is compiled on machines with a different concept of int [I've personally worked with systems where int is 16, 32, or 64 bits], it'll still have at least 32 bits of precision when you use int_least32_t).
Your teacher is likely sticking to int because simple arithmetic on "human comprehensible" numbers doesn't need anything bigger on modern desktop/laptop class machines with 32 bit int (the representable range runs from roughly -2.1 billion to 2.1 billion, and toy problems for new programmers don't need more than that). In more advanced classes, the distinction between signed and unsigned types will become more important, as will correctly sizing your types, but for now, it just doesn't matter.

There is one exception to this rule. signed is basically only used in conjunction with char (which by default has implementation-defined signedness, and is distinct from both unsigned char and signed char, even if it behaves the same as one of them); it's redundant on anything else. So if you need a signed char-sized value to do math with, you have to use signed char. 99% of the time though, you'd just use int8_t or int_least8_t in that case, but it's something you might see in older code (or code written by people who know the problems with plain char, but not the better solutions).

Note that fixed-width types are required to exist only if the implementation directly supports the type. General purpose code should use the _least or _fast versions. Unless you're writing to hardware you don't need to enforce exact sizes.

@PeteBecker: Yep. But >95% of all code I've seen using these types ignores that issue and uses int32_t or the like anyway, probably because the _least and _fast names are just too unwieldy. It's not a great system.

Reasonable case to be made for int32_l and int32_f to live along side int32_t, but I fear the one-letter difference will result in readability problems.

@ShadowRanger -- I suspect that's mostly a combination of ignorance and laziness. The names aren't a big issue; just use a typedef.

@user4581301   Not just the one letter difference.   On a lot of screens, lower case l is hard to distinguish from the digit 1.   And using one just after a digit (even with an intervening underscore) increases odds of a quick typing programmer typing another digit.

The "portability nightmares" with int, long, etc, in my experience are due to programmer laziness.   The most common is not thinking through what range of values is needed and picking a type guaranteed able to reliably represent (at least) that range   (e.g. using an int when there is a need to represent values -100000 to 100000 and the code is still required/expected to work with an [older] 16-bit compiler).  That thought process is often necessary, is a small effort, but often not done - and that causes portability problems later.

@Peter: I don't blame new programmers for not considering these things; they usually don't encounter the problems, and too few courses teach these things. I find it to be more ignorance than laziness. If you've only ever programmed for one target, it doesn't even matter, but then you get used to thinking of long as a 64 bit type on the 64 bit *NIX systems you usually target, and get bitten when you assume it'll work the same way on 64 bit Windows. It's only once you get bitten (often with a large project that needs porting and breaks in random places) that you tend to learn these things.

Nothing teaches lessons that stay in the brain for a long, long time quite like a big box of "Oh !" getting dropped on your head.

@ShadowRanger   I don't blame new programmers either.   Ignorance is where we all start with programming (in C++, or any other language) and teaching material is [for want of a better description] patchy in its quality.    But I've seen programmers with several years experience - and who claim to be experts - doing these things.
